# Document to improve communication between team

Tags: team, communication

I don't know where or how to search for such a thing but... As I was working on my last project something occurred to me. A simple change to a dialog box became a month of work because of lack of understanding between people. Everybody knows how hard is to communicate effectively between teams (ui, ux, devs...).

Sometimes what is lost in communication means working in the dark, and lots of times things are 'missed'. Do you know any kind of template with key questions for a first meeting on a project, for instance? Something that we could use that would allow me to say, after the first meeting, "ok! Now I know this and this and that. I have what I need to start..."

I know a lot of people with the sensibility to share what I need to know about a project, but most of the times, hours of conversations become 2 minutes of useful action points. I don't want to stop talking to people but some kind of script that would help me during the path would help.

Answer (score 3):

In a first meeting really what you are looking at is the big picture, the overall scope, or strategy. That should provide the foundations for what everyone else in the team needs.

The sorts of questions might be:

1. Who is this for? (Target audience)
2. What do they need to do? (User end-goal)
3. What's the best way to get there? (Actual functionality/solution - without technical information yet)

And if it's an existing product/service, you may want to look at what presenting problem is, but that can lead you down rabbit trails without the overall strategy worked out.

Any of those questions can be further expanded. Search for user research, perhaps, which includes things like user personas and user scenarios.

But, it sounds like you are thinking about something very small, so you won't need to expand on those questions. Nevertheless, for every website/app/product/service you must have the big picture worked out in writing, otherwise, everyone will be all over the place, as you describe.

So, you've worked out the big picture - how do you get to the stage of saying, for each person, what do I need to do?

The term you might need to use here is "steps in user experience design" or "steps in software project management". Then you always know what the next step will be, whether it's the first meeting or midway through.

**Possible need for a project manager**

It's hard to know from your question, but it seems like "lost in communication" and confusion relates to a lack of a single point of command - i.e. a manager. If people don't know what to do, you need to choose a single source of truth - whether a person like a manager or at least someone with final say - to get things moving.

**Software that helps**

To help with communication, your team at all times needs to know the big picture (as above), what has already been decided along the way, and what they need to do next. There are many project management tools that help with exactly that, a good free one might be Trello.

Essentially, you want the whole project written down, and a project leader who will make sure that each part of the project is being done, and one single person who will make sure it's all going to fit well together.

Answer (score 0):

Along the general lines of communication between teams, there are two main elements that need to be addressed.

The first, as you have already mentioned, is about the content that needs to be communicated, such as project scope, deliverable, etc. I think your frustration with meetings might come from actually just having a brief agenda so that whoever is running the meeting can always pull the focus back to the agreed agenda first instead of sidetracking because there wasn't a focus for the meeting.

The second, which is generally neglected, is having a good standard for the documentation. By this I mean agreeing on a set of standard to document information so that everyone (BAs, UXers and developers) can understand and talk to, and also having a defined process for who has responsibility over which aspects of the content to create, maintain and update.

And the best way to address both elements is to work collectively and collaboratively as a team to set those standards for communication at the beginning (or very early on) in the project so you don't end up having to spend lots of time on this while everyone is busy working, in addition to the amount of information and documentation building up.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers.

### My main goal is to understand how efficient can we be on capturing and registering activable information.

I think the questions 'who?', 'what goal?' and 'how' are very important.
I found some interesting things under the 'problem statement' umbrella:

https://pages.18f.gov/lean-product-design/2-problem-statement/
https://medium.com/@MattPLavoie/what-s-your-problem-e45b31bf08dd
https://medium.com/eightshapes-llc/how-to-build-a-problem-statement-d1f21713720b